# Including a PDF file in a PDF file generated by FOP

Tags: php, pdf, apache-fop

I'm using FOP to generate PDF files.

What's the best way to either include another PDF file in a PDF generated by FOP or to cook multiple PDF files together using PHP?

Comment: Use Latex instead. It is free, but has to run on the server.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan Why "instead"? Can latex merge PDF files? If you suggest latex instead of FOP, you're out of line I think.

Comment: I'd like to second @Savageman. I use both (La)Tex and XSL-FO/FOP in several locations and both have their use cases. And FOP is free, too.

Answer (score 1):

After creation with FOP, as kind of post-processing, I'd suggest to take a look at the [PDF toolkit](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/). In it's own words:

> If PDF is electronic paper, then pdftk is an electronic staple-remover, hole-punch, binder, secret-decoder-ring, and X-Ray-glasses. Pdftk is a simple tool for doing everyday things with PDF documents.

I used this in some projects where I needed to re-sort FOP's output into a printable page order.

Unfortunately it's neither Java nor PHP, but it's useful in so many ways, that I think it needs mentioning nonetheless. And it's a small standalone, that you can perhaps simply set in your server's path...

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you 
either use some commandline tool e.g. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/
or combine the pdfs using the fpdi class - http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/